# Get numbers after string php regex

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex that can actually get any number that is inserted after "ab" and "cr". For example, I have a string like this:

```
rw200-208-ab66
fg200-cr30-201
```

I need to print `ab66` and `cr30`.

I have tried using `strpos`:

```
if (strpos($part,'ab') !== false) {
            $a = explode("ab", $part);
           echo 'ab'.$a[1];
    }
```

That does not work for the second item.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
(?>ab|cr)\d+
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/NUzWtA):

```
$re = "#(?>ab|cr)\d+#"; 
$str = "rw200-208-ab66\nfg200-cr30-201"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ab66
    [1] => cr30
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\K` to discard the previously matched chars from printing at the final. The below regex would give you the number which exists next to `ab`
 or `cr`.

```
(?:ab|cr)\K\d+
```

To get the number with alphabets also, use

```
preg_match_all('~(?:ab|cr)\d+~', $str, $match);
```

Comment: or `(?:ab|cr)(\d+)` use this regex and then get the number from group index 1.